# Howto Work with Record Separator in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I have a data that looks like this

```
--
read50_1: read1391364_2,read3529226_1,
--
read46_2: read916_1,read178252_2,read1336397_1,read1824459_2,
read916_1: read0_1
--
read34_1: read209771_2,
--
read32_2: read520377_2,
```

What I want to do is to access the entry excluding the record separator "--".

But why this code doesn't do it?

```
my  $INFILE_file_name = "myfile.txt";      # input file name
my $content = '';
open ( INFILE, '<', $INFILE_file_name )
    or croak "$0 : failed to open input file $INFILE_file_name : $!\n";

{
    local $/ = "--";

    $content = <INFILE>;
    print "$content\n";

}

close ( INFILE );           # close input file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I'm guessing you meant

```
local $/ = "--\n"; # or maybe "\n--\n"
```

(If you do use `"\n--\n"`, then the first line will no longer be considered a record separator, but will be part of the first record.  You might want to read that first `--` line *before* changing `$/`.)

Remember that `$/` is not removed by the [`<IN>`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators) operator.  Use [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) to do that.

Secondly, the file begins with the record separator, so the first record will be blank.

```
{
    local $/ = "--\n";

    while ($content = <INFILE>) {
      chomp $content;
      print "$content\n" if $content; # Skip empty records
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m not completely certain why people so often forget to `chomp`. I think it may be because some language’s `readline` or `gets` function already does that for them, but I may be confusing cause and effect here. Perl only autochomps on the implicit loop from `-n` or `-p`.

Comment: @tchrist - Huh? autochomping only happens if you use `-l`, too

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use autodie;
use Data::Dump 'pp';

open my $file, "<", "input.txt";
{
    local $/ = "--\n";
    say pp <$file>;
}
close $file;
```

And the output:

```
(
  "--\n",
  "read50_1: read1391364_2,read3529226_1,\n--\n",
  "read46_2: read916_1,read178252_2,read1336397_1,read1824459_2,\nread916_1: read0_1\n--\n",
  "read34_1: read209771_2,\n--\n",
  "read32_2: read520377_2,\n",
)
```

In other words, reading does not strip the input record separator. You might want something like this:

```
open my $file, "<", "input.txt";
{
    local $/ = "--\n";
    for (<$file>) {
        chomp;
        s/\n//g;
        say "<$_>";
    }
}
close $file;
```

Which gives:

```
<>
<read50_1: read1391364_2,read3529226_1,>
<read46_2: read916_1,read178252_2,read1336397_1,read1824459_2,read916_1: read0_1>
<read34_1: read209771_2,>
<read32_2: read520377_2,>
```

---

As a side note, you should [use the three-arg open](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html) and you might be interested in [autodie](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autodie) so that you won’t have to write the `or die` boilerplate.

Comment: The several reasons to use three-arg open  do not apply in this case. And you haven’t even addressed them in your solution, so why bother?

Answer (score 2):

You could also just do:

```
while(<INFILE>) {
        print unless(/\s*--\s*/);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While using the record separator here is a possibility, it's not a very good solution unless the '--'s imply some meaningful grouping of data (that will be used). If the purpose is to merely filter out the '--'s, use loop control.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'myFile.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Unable to open $file: $!";

while ( <$fh> ) {   # Read text file line-by-line

    next if /^--/;  # Skips current line if it begins with '--'
    print;          # Will only execute if line doesn't begin with '--'
}

close $fh;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my  $INFILE_file_name = "myfile.txt";
my @content = ( );
open ( INFILE, '<', $INFILE_file_name );
@content = <INFILE>;
close ( INFILE );

foreach my $line (@content) {
    $line =~ s/^\s+//;
    $line =~ s/\s+$//;
    if ($line eq '--') {
        next;
    }
    print $line . "\n";
}
```

From that, you would be able to access the records line by line, without the `--` separator. Also, if you want to just put it in one variable instead of an array, you can just:

```
$file .= $line . "\n";
```

Comment: I use hope you had a couple of helpful pragmas at the top of that program: `use autodie` and some flavor of `use open` or equivalent.  But why in the world would you read the whole file into memory before doing linewise processing on it?

Answer (score 1):

`$content = <INFILE>` fetches only the next line which ends with the characters in `$/`. It should be wrapped in a loop to get all the lines.

```
while ( $content = <INFILE> ) {
    chomp $content;
    print "$content\n";
}
```

Modern Perl users stay away from bareword filehandles. Instead, use lexical variables as filehandles. To know why lexical variables are preferred to bareword filehandles, read: [Bareword uppercase filehandles](https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/index.cgi?bareword_uppercase_filehandles).

Comment: That will fail if the last line doesn’t end in the `$/`, because `chomp` will return 0, and you’ll miss the last line! That’s why the `chomp` is usually done inside the `while` loop. I really don’t think his problem lies in whether he’s using a direct or indirect filehandle.

Comment: tchrist: Oh yes, I completely missed that! I always `chomp` within the loop body as well. However, got it wrong this time. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

local $/="--\n";
while(chomp($_=)){print;}